# Final call of __destruct missing when forking

Tags: php, destructor, fork

today I ran in some strange behaviour of PHP:

When forking, every child triggers a __destruct function, as they should, but after the last child finishes, there is no more call of __destruct from the parent!

My code:

```
class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $pid = pcntl_fork();
            if (!$pid) {
                print("child ".$i."\n");
                exit($i);
            }
            while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
                $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
                print("child ".$status." finished\n");
            }
            print("parent still alive\n");
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        print("destruct\n");
    }
}
```

This would print the following into my debian shell:

```
child 0
destruct
child 0 finished
child 1
destruct
child 1 finished
child 2
destruct
child 2 finished
child 3
destruct
child 3 finished
parent still alive
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which PHP version? 5.4.34 & 5.5.9 both work OK here, and call the final destruct. Are you sure your parent process actually finishes? No other code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use PHP 5.5.9, after the forking finished, the script processes some other code. This evening I will post my whole code, this was just some sort of simplified example.